# override component mui v5 react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using mui v5 and I'm trying to override the Container component to be have a padding of 4rem.
here is a simple code example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import theme from "./theme";

const MyContainer = styled(Container, {})`
  padding-left: 4rem;
  background-color: aqua;
`;

export default function App() {
   return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
         <CssBaseline />
         <MyContainer maxWidth="xl">
            <div>test</div>
         </MyContainer>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>,
   );
}
```

But this yields no results.
here is a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-leakey-xumyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use make use of `shouldForwardProp` of mui v5.

```
const MyContainer = styled(Container, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop
})(({ padding }) => ({
  padding: padding,
  backgroundColor: "aqua"
}));
```

You can check forked codesandbox here
[open this](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-boyd-vfl1r?file=/src/App.js:271-420)

Comment: it didn't work also

Comment: @boumourilyass. Can you create a codesandbox?

Comment: yes, here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-leakey-xumyd . Thank you.

Comment: @boumourilyass. I've edited my answer. Pls take a look

Comment: @boumour ilyass. Can you accept the answer and upvote it too? thanks

Comment: i tried to, but it tells me that i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. Sorry

Comment: You can accept the answer then. no need for the upvote